# Extract US phone numbers from a string

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to extract US only phone numbers from a string.

I have looked around the web/SO but have not found any suitable solution for my needs.

To be honest, I have 2.5 years of experience in Web Programming but I suck at RegEX.

Here is only RegEX I wrote `(\d{3}+\-\d{3}+\-\d{4}+)`

but it only detects `589-845-2889`

Here are phone numbers I want to extract.

```
589-845-2889

(589)-845-2889

589.845.2889

589 845 2889

5898452889

(589) 845 2889
```

Please tell me how can I achieve this feat in single Regex for PHP.

**EDIT:**

If you feel any other format of US number a user can enter, also mention that as well, and include that in RegEX as well.

**P.S:**

Actually I am trying to scrape Craiglist and user may have posted their phone number in any possible format.

Comment: Should `589 845-2889` be a match?

Comment: Yes, any possible way a user can enter his number

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP (PCRE) you can use this regex based on [conditional subpatterns](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.conditional.php):

```
(\()?\d{3}(?(1)\))[-.\h]?\d{3}[-.\h]?\d{4}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cP3aP1/1)

- `(\()?` matches optional `(` and captures it in group #1
- `(?(1)\))` is *conditional pattern* that matches closing `)` only if group #1 is not null i.e. `(` is present on left of the match.

Comment: Why it has weird result?  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b3b6cf795b8026c85d5c9bbdc04943978e94e8d0

Comment: I mean, it returns 2 arrays, 1st array is fine, what is 2nd array is all about?

Comment: You should be using `var_dump($result[0]);` for your results. [Check this demo now](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1cc85f77cb46becf28711e9162c8ea601d752375)

Comment: 2nd array or `$result[1]` is showing first captured group which gets populated only when input starts with `(`

Comment: +1 This has comments which will actually help the user going forward. Other answers are just solutions. Teach a man how to fish and all that.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, it works:

```
^(\((\d{3})\)|(\d{3}))[\s\-\.]?\d{3}[\s\-\.]?\d{4}
```

tested in notepad++